# Prove that a group of order 45 is necessarily abelian by Sylows' Theorems

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

So far, my attempt of proof looks like this:

$\#G =45=3^2\times 5$, so:

- By the 1st Sylow Theorem that G has p-subgroups of order 5, 9 and 3.
- By the 3rd theorem, the p-subgroups of order 5 and 9 have to be unique: 
  $$n_5 = 1 \text{ (mod } 5), n_5 |9 \implies n_5=1$$
  The proof is analogous for $P_9$ and so they're both normal in G (by adding the 2nd Theorem, all the p-subgroups are conjugate and there can't be any conjugate of $P_5$ or $P_9$ that isn't the group itself, since we've already shown they're unique).
- For every p-subgroup, we know it's center is not trivial, so $\#Z(G)>1$

Now, I'm having trouble linking the information about its p-subgroups to the equation: $$\#G = \# Z(G) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty[G:N(x_i)]$$ 
I feel like there's something quite obvious I'm missing but I can't put my finger on it.

I've looked into [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791370/showing-that-a-group-of-order-45-is-abelian) post also, but the example they give has references to a "Corolary 15" to show that the center has either order 6 or 48, but the theorem isn't there so idk what theorem they're refering too.

Comment: $G$ is the direct product of its sylow subgroups, which are both abelian.

Comment: Why is G a direct product of its sylow subgroups though? Is there a theorem behind that?

Comment: yeah, if i'm not mistaken, it will be whenever all of its sylow subgroups are normal.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2114865/403337